Why manim -pql return SSLCertVerificationError?
I have the code:
from manim import *

class CountingScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        number = DecimalNumber()
        number.set_color(WHITE)

        self.add(number)

        self.wait(3)

It should render the video with a digit, but when you type manim -pql main.py CountingScene i'm getting an error:
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'www.latexcluster.org'. (_ssl.c:992)
packages "certifi" I have installed. What is the mistake?

It seems to be pretty clear -- the remote site has an invalid SSL certificate. I don't know why manim needs to consult an Internet site, but the problem is at their end.
